# How to solve this issue in angular?

Tags: angular

```
ERROR Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_StudentDetailsService -> _StudentDetailsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4483:21)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4787:27)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4787:27)
    at injectInjectorOnly (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2451:36)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), 
<anonymous>:2457:59)
    at Object.StudentDetailsService_Factory [as factory] (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4198:68)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4887:33)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2426:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4886:9)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4782:23) {
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [
    '_StudentDetailsService',
    '_StudentDetailsService',
    '_HttpClient',
    '_HttpClient'
  ]
}
Error [NullInjectorError]: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_StudentDetailsService -> _StudentDetailsService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4483:21)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4787:27)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4787:27)
    at injectInjectorOnly (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2451:36)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), 
<anonymous>:2457:59)
    at Object.StudentDetailsService_Factory [as factory] (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4198:68)
    at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4887:33)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2426:5)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4886:9)
    at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4782:23) {
  ngTempTokenPath: null,
  ngTokenPath: [
    '_StudentDetailsService',
    '_StudentDetailsService',
    '_HttpClient',
    '_HttpClient'
  ]
}
1:05:39 PM [vite] Internal server error: R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_StudentDetailsService -> _StudentDetailsService -> _HttpClient 
-> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!
      at NullInjector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4483:21)
      at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4787:27)
      at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4787:27)
      at injectInjectorOnly (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2451:36)
      at Module.ɵɵinject (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2457:59)
      at Object.StudentDetailsService_Factory [as factory] (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4198:68)
      at eval (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4887:33)
      at runInInjectorProfilerContext (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:2426:5)
      at R3Injector.hydrate (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4886:9)
      at R3Injector.get (eval at instantiateModule (file:///D:/New%20folder/NewAngular/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:56049:28), <anonymous>:4782:23)
```

This is my error when I set the http request for my local student.json file then shown this error in terminal?

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please add the code that causes the error